# Prolog zodiacal and leap year

Tags: prolog

i'm trying to do something that tell me the zodiacal sign and if the year is leap year all of this in Prolog

and everything looks great but it's shows me an error when I try to do the cosnult

here is my code

```
    /* 7. Horóscopo
 horoscopo(Signo,DiaIni,MesIni,DiaFin,MesFin)
<- son del signo Signo los nacidos entre el Dia
Ini/MesIni y el DiaFin/MesFin */


horoscopo(aries,21,3,21,4).
horoscopo(tauro,21,4,21,5).
horoscopo(geminis,21,5,21,6).
horoscopo(cancer,21,6,21,7).
horoscopo(leo,21,7,21,8).
horoscopo(virgo,21,8,21,9).
horoscopo(libra,21,9,21,10).
horoscopo(escorpio,21,10,21,11).
horoscopo(sagitario,21,11,21,12).
horoscopo(capricornio,21,12,21,1).
horoscopo(acuario,21,1,21,2).
horoscopo(piscis,21,2,21,3).


mes(1,31,enero).
mes(2,28,febrero).
mes(3,31,marzo).
mes(4,30,abril).
mes(5,31,mayo).
mes(6,30,junio).
mes(7,31,julio).
mes(8,31,agosto).
mes(9,30,septiembre).
mes(10,31,octubre).
mes(11,30,noviembre).
mes(12,31,diciembre).

signo(Dia,Mes,Signo) :-horoscopo(Signo,D1,M1,D2,M2),((Mes=M1,Dia>=D1,mes(M1,D,_),Dia=<D);(Mes=M2,Dia=<D2,Dia>0)).


anio_bisiesto(L) :-
    partition(es_anio_bisiesto,L,LIn,LOut),
    format('año bisiesto:~w~n',[LIn]),
    format('no año bisiesto:~w~n',[LOut]).


corre:-write('Presiona s para salir, c para continuar: '),
read(Z),
proceso(Z).

proceso(c):-write('Introduce tu día de nacimiento: '),
read(X),
write('Introduce tu mes de nacimiento: '),
read(Y),
calcula(X,Y).

write('Introduce el año: '),
read(a).

es_anio_bisiesto(anio) :-
    R4 is anio mod 4,
    R100 is anio mod 100,
    R400 is anio mod 400,
    ((R4 = 0, R100 \= 0); R400 = 0).

proceso(s):-!.

calcula(X,Y):-write('Tu signo es: '),
signo(X,Y,Signo),
write(Signo),nl,corre.
```

and this is my error

```
ERROR: c:/users/alaenvargut/desktop/a.pl:53:
        Full stop in clause-body?  Cannot redefine ,/2
Warning: c:/users/alaenvargut/desktop/a.pl:62:
        Clauses of proceso/1 are not together in the source-file
% c:/Users/Alaenvargut/Desktop/a.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 1 clauses
```

please help me

and sorry about mi bad english :S please

Comment: i fix the first part but i can't get where my error is at line 62 help!!

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
proceso(c):-write('Introduce tu día de nacimiento: '),
read(X),
write('Introduce tu mes de nacimiento: '),
read(Y),
calcula(X,Y).
/*
write('Introduce el año: '),
read(a).

es_anio_bisiesto(anio) :-
    R4 is anio mod 4,
    R100 is anio mod 100,
    R400 is anio mod 400,
    ((R4 = 0, R100 \= 0); R400 = 0).
*/
proceso(s):-!.
```

I think you're refining your code: 
make `anio` a variable and move `es_anio_bisiesto` after `proceso(s):-!.`